# How to group continues tuples and pick maximum one in a list by Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have something like this:

```py
[
  (1, 5),
  (2, 24),
  (3, 14),  # I need to find the `max` value from these
  
  # Increment changes

  (22, 78),
  (23, 85),
  (24, 92),
  (25, 56),  # I need to find the `max` value from these

  # This story would continue with different increments in ID and Value

]
```

My question is: How can I do this?

Comment: not sure what you want to accomplish here. Please share sample input and output.

Comment: will the first value of the tuple always be in order?

Comment: So you want to break the tuples into groups based on the discontinuities in the first element?

Comment: Can you please describe *in words* what you are trying to do? What do you consider "the `max` value" – the largest tuple, the largest index, the largest tail? What do you consider "these"? Consecutive indices? Same 10-place digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `groupby` of `itertools` and the `enumerate` function to locate all the consecutive groups. Then when you have those groups, you can use the `max` operation to get the correct values.

```
for k, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(values), key=lambda x: x[0] - x[1][0]):
    print(k, [val for idx, (id, val) in list(group)])
```

Will result in

```
-1 [5, 24, 14]
-19 [78, 85, 92, 56]
```

Now you can get the maximum value using `max`

```
max([val for idx, (id, val) in list(group)])
```

Which will return `24` and `92`.

Comment: Clever grouping function to find contiguous groups. That's been bugging me for a while, since all slice-zip-and-neighbour-diff based approaches are either clunky or leave one element out on the rim :) have an uptick!

Comment: @Thymen Really helpful!